# How to handle no data found when calling restTemplate.getForObject

Tags: java, mongodb, resttemplate, restheart

I am calling `restTemplate.getForObject` to retrieve a certain value from Mongo DB. How to deal the exception if the expected data is not found in the DB?

```java
Object[] mongodata = restTemplate.getForObject(resulturl,Object[].class,keyval);
list = Arrays.asList(mongodata);
```

where keyval is a string that contains a json and resulturl is the url for calling mongo

Comment: can you share sample code you did

Comment: @PrashantThorat : Have added. can you check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have two main options:

1. Simply wrap the `RestTemplate` call in a `try-catch` block and handle the error (in case of 404 not found response, it would be the `HttpClientErrorException`). Something like

```java
try {
  Object[] mongodata = restTemplate.getForObject(resulturl,Object[].class,keyval);
  list = Arrays.asList(mongodata);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
  if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    throw e;
  } 
}
```

2. Implement a `ResponseErrorHandler`.

See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling) post on Baeldung for an example.

Comment: Only the line with the getForObject() need to be inside try?

Comment: Yes, just make sure variables are initialized in correct scopes.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer so that others know that it has been solved.

Comment: You should be able to also mark the answer as accepted - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers